# How do I increase Google PageSpeed insight Score on mobile?

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I have a wordpress website which is fast in loading too but it's Google speed insight scores are low. I reached out some developers to improve score but they said your theme isn't fully compatible and you need to change it. My website is [myQuery.co.uk](https://myquery.co.uk/) and it is using a wordpress theme called Scisco. Can anyone help me to improve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the AMP version for mobile devices you can easily find the plugin to create the AMP version of your website.
Here is the plugin I have used many times "https://wordpress.org/plugins/accelerated-mobile-pages/" to make my website speed faster for mobile.
Also, add this plugin "https://wordpress.org/plugins/leverage-browser-caching/" for leverage browsing cache. This will improve your speed and help in gaining a good score with google page speed insights.
You can reach me for any kind of help.

Thank You,
Usman Khalid

Comment: Thanks Khalid, I'll try your suggested method and will revert you.